# Inline DTD error: StartTag: invalid element name

Tags: xml, dtd

I wrote xml file and everything worked fine until I added dtd code generated from some site. Now i have error. Please help me
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 3 at column 2: StartTag: invalid element name
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!ELEMENT collection (storage)>
<!ATTLIST collection
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''>

<!ELEMENT storage (genre)+>
<!ATTLIST storage
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''>

<!ELEMENT genre (series)+>
<!ATTLIST genre
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''
  domain CDATA #REQUIRED>

<!ELEMENT series (title,author,number,country)>
<!ATTLIST series
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''>

<!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST title
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''>

<!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST author
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''>

<!ELEMENT number (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST number
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''>

<!ELEMENT country (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST country
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''>

<collection>
    <storage>
        <genre domain="horror">
            <series>
                <title>The Walking Dead</title>
                <author>Frank Darabont</author>
                <number>1</number>
                <country>USA</country>
            </series>
            <series>
                <title>The Strain</title>
                <author>Guillermo del Toro</author>
                <number>11</number>
                <country>Canada</country>
            </series>
            <series>
                <title>Tales from the Crypt</title>
                <author>Bill Gaines</author>
                <number>12</number>
                <country>USA</country>
            </series>
        </genre>
        <genre domain="science fiction">
            <series>
                <title>Stranger Things</title>
                <author>Duffer brothers</author>
                <number>4</number>
                <country>USA</country>
            </series>
            <series>
                <title>The 100</title>
                <author>Jason Rothenberg</author>
                <number>2</number>
                <country>USA</country>
            </series>
            <series>
                <title>The 4400</title>
                <author>Rene Echevarria</author>
                <number>3</number>
                <country>Canada</country>
            </series>
            <series>
                <title>The Twilight Zone</title>
                <author>Rod Serling</author>
                <number>5</number>
                <country>USA</country>
            </series>
        </genre>
        <genre domain="comedy">
            <series>
                <title>Two and a Half Men</title>
                <author>Chuck Lorre</author>                
                <number>6</number>
                <country>USA</country>
            </series>
            <series>
                <title>Anger Management</title>
                <author>Bruce Helford</author>
                <number>7</number>
                <country>USA</country>
            </series>
            <series>
                <title>Family Guy</title>
                <author>Seth MacFarlane</author>
                <number>8</number>
                <country>USA</country>
            </series>
            <series>
                <title>The Simpsons</title>
                <author>Matt Groening</author>              
                <number>9</number>
                <country>USA</country>
            </series>
        </genre>
        <genre domain="drama">
            <series>
                <title>House of Cards</title>
                <author>Beau Willimon</author>
                <number>13</number>
                <country>USA</country>
            </series>
            <series>
                <title>Riverdale</title>
                <author>Roberto Aguirre-Sacasa</author>
                <number>14</number>
                <country>Canada</country>
            </series>
            <series>
                <title>Supernatural</title>
                <author>Eric Kripke</author>
                <number>15</number>
                <country>USA</country>
            </series>
        </genre>
    </storage>
</collection>
```

I am writing in xml for the first time :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no `<!DOCTYPE collection [ ... ]>` in the DTD part of the XML. That should be around all those definitions.

Comment: So i should add <!DOCTYPE collection [ and here past dtd ]>??

Comment: Ok and now it is showing me document tree. This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below. So it is good?

Comment: @ErykMatysiak: if a browser shows it like that, probably yes, it's good. If it's really good you can only say with a validation tool.

Answer (score 0):

Your pretty much spot on, your just missing the DOCTYPE tag.

You need the DOCTYPE tag when embedding the DTD in an XML document, you don't need it when the DTD is in its own file, have a look at XML [DOCTYPE reference](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/XML/DocType.aspx).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE collection [
    <!ELEMENT collection (storage)>
    <!ATTLIST collection
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''>
    <!ELEMENT storage (genre)+>
    <!ATTLIST storage
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''>
    <!ELEMENT genre (series)+>
    <!ATTLIST genre
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''
  domain CDATA #REQUIRED>
    <!ELEMENT series (title,author,number,country)>
    <!ATTLIST series
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''>
    <!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>
    <!ATTLIST title
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''>
    <!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>
    <!ATTLIST author
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''>
    <!ELEMENT number (#PCDATA)>
    <!ATTLIST number
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''>
    <!ELEMENT country (#PCDATA)>
    <!ATTLIST country
  xmlns CDATA #FIXED ''>
]>
<collection>
...
```